Verifying properties of a topology for this definition of Zariski Topology
[Here] on page 13,(https://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~srg/Lecnotes/AfsPuneLecNotes.pdf) they define the the topology as :
Let $A$ be a given ring. Given any subset $E$ of $A$ define:
$V(E) := \{ \mathfrak{p} \in Spec(A) | E \subseteq \mathfrak{p}\}$.
Then

$V(0) = Spec(A)$, $V(1) = \phi$.

$\cap_{\alpha} V(E_{\alpha}) = V( \cup_{\alpha} E_{\alpha})$

$\cap^{m} V(E_i) = V(\cap^{m} E_i)$


makes it a topology.
However I am not able to verify the third property.
Let $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $E_1= \{3\}, E_2=\{2\}$. Then since the intersection is $\{0\}$, $V(\{0\}) = Spec(A)$ where as $V(E_1) \cap V(E_2) = \phi$.
What is the mistake ? If the definition is correct can you prove the 3rd property. One of the directions is obvious, just prove the other direction.

There are several things wrong in what you wrote down:

The LHS of 3 should be a finite union, $\bigcup_{i=1}^m V(E_i)$, instead of intersection.
The intersection of $\{2\}$ and $\{3\}$ is the empty set, not $\{0\}$. This doesn’t affect much since $V(\{0\}) = V(\varnothing) = \text{Spec}(A)$.
Even after fixing these two issues, item 3 is still wrong, since $V(2) \cup V(3) = \{2\mathbb{Z}, 3\mathbb{Z}\} \neq \text{Spec}(A) = V(\{2\} \cap \{3\})$. The correct statement should have been,

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^m V(E_i) = V\left(\prod_{i=1}^m E_i \right)$$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;$where $\prod_{i=1}^m E_i = \{\prod_{i=1}^m x_i: x_i \in E_i, \forall 1 \leq i \leq m\}$. The author likely made a typo.

For ideals, you can also take the intersection instead of the product. Both work.

@MartinBrandenburg Ah, yes. That might actually be a likelier explanation for why the typo was made in the first place - the author was intending for $E_i$ to be ideals.

When $E_i$'s are ideals, its the standard definition. But in the source (see the link) this was the definition and I am not sure if its right.

@emmy As I noted, the author likely made a typo. Either they meant $E_i$ to be ideals and forgot to say that, or they meant $\prod$ instead of $\bigcap$.
